# How to create popup that after close shows data on previous page?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have my shop page and would like to create a function allowing users to upload photos from their phones. I need a popup that shows a QR code, and after it closes, the photos appear on my previous page.

**How to create that popup?**

I tried with:

```
window.open("qr.html", "_blank", "left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320");
```

but it does not fix the problem, I need code to start after this popup closes.
How to do it?

Comment: You will most likely have to create a custom modal for something like this. The HTML dialog element might be useful for this project: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:modal

Comment: i fixed it using onbeforeunload, thanks for anser!